# 403 when making axios POST request

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, caml-query, 403, post

I have a feature that loads a map onto a page, and 5% of the time I'm hit with a 403 error and the map data doesn't load properly. I've had a very difficult time with triggering the error, but I was able to catch it and take screenshots (see below).

When the page refreshes, a GET request occurs that loads the right data, and then a POST request occurs that loads the right map. There are multiple pages, each with their own content and maps, and a user can easily navigate between pages.

i.e. When the Mordor page loads, the data for the Mordor map loads simultaneously. When I navigate to the Lothlorien page, the data for the Lothlorien map loads.

Any thoughts on what's causing this? As I said, although this error happens rarely I do want to get to the bottom of it, in order to prevent future complications down the line.

Notes:

- I used to have an issue to where the 403 error happened frequently (if the page was idle), but I resolved it by doing a `if resp.status === 403, window.location.reload`. That fixed the problem, but I've wondered if the issue I'm experiencing now is related to it and "leaking through", so to speak.
- `webpack-internal` shows up in the console (see screenshots), but searching for 403 errors with webpack comes up short.
- I'm using `empty()` throughout the project, so that the old data doesn't remain on the page.

---

```js
async function loadMaps(){
    let ret = axios.post( // ${location} is referenced at an earlier point, and always works
        `${_Something}/something/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Middle Earth Maps')/GetItems`,{
        "query": {"__metadata": {"type":"SP.CamlQuery"}, "ViewXml": `<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MiddleEarthMaps'/><Value Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>${location}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>`}
        }, {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "include",
            mode: "no-cors",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            }
    }).then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.status)
        // in here there's other code that behaves as intended (95% of the time)
    }).catch(err => {
        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) { // I use this for the main page of the project, and it works as intended
            window.location.reload();
        }

        console.log("Error during loadMaps");
        console.log(err);
        return false;
     });
    return ret;
}
```

[403 in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVlPk.png)

[The debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQk59.jpg)

[Local in the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzNvQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a chat with a senior dev, and although they're not 100% sure of the cause they believe it had to do with the POST request and a timing delay.

We converted the POST to a GET and installs a package that reloads the page if an axios call fails a certain number of times.

The problem hasn't happened since, and I hope it stays that way.